# Expanding a restriction on acceptable inputs in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, validation

I have the following code restricting the inputs of a 2-digit text box. I wanted to know if there is a way for me to prevent '00' from being entered if '0' exists already in the field:

```
Private Sub txtLLFiftyFifty_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtLLSwapQuestion.KeyPress, txtLLPlusOne.KeyPress, txtLLPhoneFriend.KeyPress, txtLLJumpQuestion.KeyPress, txtLLFiftyFifty.KeyPress, txtLLCrystalBall.KeyPress, txtLLAskExpert.KeyPress, txtLLAskAudience.KeyPress
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48) Or (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried the following conditional but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 48) And Me.Text = "0" Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
```

Comment: rather than getting involved in the user's every keystroke, you could avoid all the issues using a numericupdown

Comment: YES... I completely forgot about that control...